# Qt Threads: Signals/Slots 2 Objects (1 Singleton) created in Main Thread and called in another Thread

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Problem:
I've got 2 objects wich are both created and connected in the main thread. One of the objects is a Singleton.
Now I want to call a method from the singleton in another thread and emit a signal in it.
The Problem is, that the connected slot is not called after the signal was emitted. Am I doing something wrong or is connect() not capable of it?

The Second Thread should process some folders and call a method from the singleton object, which is emitting the signal, with the result of the process.

The Code looks something like this (not working):

```cpp
void main() {
    Singleton* singleton = Singleton::getInstance();
    ShowResult* show = new Showesult();
    connect(singleton, SIGNAL(itemsset(Items)), show, SLOT(showresult(Items)));
    Process* p = new Process();
    QThread thread;
    p->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), p, SLOT(process()));
    thread.start();
}

class Process : public QObject {
    public:
        Process(){}

    public slots:
        void process() {
            // Do some work
            Singleton::getInstance()->setItems(someitems);
        }
};

class Singleton : public QObject {
    public:
        Singleton(){}

        Singleton* getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        void setitems(Items) {
            //Set items
            emit itemsset();
        }

    signals:
        void itemsset(Items);
};

class ShowResult : public QObject {
    public:
        ShowResult(){}

    public slots:
        void showresult(Items) {
            //THIS Slot is not called...
        }
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: 1. Show your actual code. Code from the above is incorrect (2). Get in the habit to always check if signal/slot connected by `bool ok = connect(...); Q_ASSERT(ok);`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The Problem was Solved some how. I removed all moc generated Files and rebuilt the whole project.